# IntelliJ Docker terminal does not accept input anymore

Tags: intellij-idea

Suddenly my Docker terminals stopped to accept keyboard input.

- the cursor in the terminal is blinking, but id does not accept any input
- even pasting text via mouse does not work (i.e. copy text, right-click in terminal, select `Paste`)

[image]

I've tried the following (nothing worked):

- restart IntelliJ
- delete the image/container
- try other containers
- use Attach, exec /bin/sh, Create terminal
- restart the PC
- all IntelliJ repair options

Notes:

- input in other IntelliJ windows works normally
- when I use `Open in terminal` from Docker-desktop, it opens a terminal with /bin/sh and the input works
- IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.3 (Ultimate Edition)

Any ideas?

Comment: Please try to download to  Docker 4.9.1

Comment: I have docker 4.10.1 installed

Comment: 4.11. still not working on idea 2022.1.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Update 28.7.2022

The issue [IDEA-297446](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-297446) is fixed in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2

### Original

I've tested this on another PC and the issue seems to be related to the Docker Desktop version

- it worked with Docker Desktop `4.9.0`
- after upgrading to `4.10.1` the IntelliJ Terminal does not accept user-input anymore

see [IDEA-297446](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-297446)

**Workaround** for now is to use Docker Desktop CLI:
[image]